# What do you call (S×V) in the HSV color model?

Tags: color, color-theory, terminology, color-spaces

What do you call the quality of a color being “vivid,” or in other words, the quality of a hue being distinct and recognizable? Mathematically speaking, what do you call (S×V) in the HSV color model?

[image: The HSV color model]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its really hard to come up with a good mathematical reasoning for color because color is not a simple vector quantity. Roughly saturation is more vivid. But in terms of a image vividity is used for a transformation that increases image contrast by adding saturation based on a convolution.

In reality its really its not so easy to do this kind of analysis in hsv colorpace since its by no means uniform, its just a simple transformation of rgb to polar form. This is convenient but has no scientific basis. In reality you should be using xyz, Lab, or hcL coordinates to do your deductions about what thins mean

But i would call it intensity